# jquery toggling checked attribute of checkbox not triggering change event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js

I want to perform some actions when the div inside which a checkbox is, is clicked. This is how I change the checked attribute of the checkbox:

```
$(".crinbox").click(function () {
  var cbox = $('input[value="crin"]');
  if (!cbox.checked) {
    cbox.attr("checked", true);
  } else if (cbox.checked) {
    cbox.attr("checked", false);
  }
});
```

And this is how I handle the change,

```
$('input[value="crin"]').on("change", function () {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $(".crin").hide();
    $('input[name="crin"').attr("value", "");
  } else if (this.checked) {
    $(".crin").show();
  }
});
```

However, I am not able to trigger the on change function for the checkbox, all this does is check the checkbox, also, I can not uncheck the checkbox once I check it with this function.

HBS :

.crin (div to hide and show):

```
<div class="crin selectt" style="{{#if check.crinChecked}}display:block{{else}}display:none{{/if}}">
  <input type="text" name="crin" value="{{fields.crin.[0]}}">
  <input type="text" name="crin" value="{{fields.crin.[1]}}">
  {{#if check.crinChecked}}{{#if fields.crinPartError}}<p style="color:red" class="error">
    {{fields.crinPartError}}
  </p>
  {{/if}}{{/if}}

</div>
```

checkbox and its div:

```
  <div class="dabba crinbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="events" value="crin" {{#if check.crinChecked}}checked{{/if}}>
    <p> Create-in </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: please add your html

Comment: @DCR Done, but I am using express-handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add :

```
cbox.trigger("change");
```

So :

```
$(".crinbox").click(function () {
  var cbox = $('input[value="crin"]');
  if (!cbox.checked) {
    cbox.attr("checked", true);
    cbox.trigger("change");
  } else if (cbox.checked) {
    cbox.attr("checked", false);
    cbox.trigger("change");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:
there was couple of things wrong with your code logic. I can explain what if this is even wanted result. But I am still confused what are you trying to achieve.

```js
$(".crinbox").click(function () {
  var cbox = $('input[name="crin"]');
  if (!cbox.is(':checked')) {
    cbox.attr("checked", true);
  } else if (cbox.is(':checked')) {
    cbox.attr("checked", false);
  }
});



$('input[name="crin"]').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
var cbox = $('input[name="crin"]');

  if (!cbox.is(':checked')) {
    $(".crin").hide();
    $(cbox).attr("value", "");
    console.clear(); 
    console.log(cbox.val());
  }
  if (cbox.is(':checked')) {
    $(".crin").show();
    $(cbox).attr("value", "crin");
    console.clear(); 
    console.log(cbox.val());
  }
  console.log("changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crinbox">test crinbox click<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="crin" value="crin"> <br>
<div class="crin">test crin<br>
</div>
```